# Aggregate with respect to condition

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I face the following problem.
I have a dataset that I simplify this way

```
df <- tibble(ID_1=c("a","a", "a","a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), ID_2 = c("a","b", "c","d", "e", "b", "a", "c", "d"), 
             other= c(1, "bu", 34, 3, 5, 6, "jud", 82, 9), exchange=c(1, 13, 34, 3, 5, 6, 8, 82, 9), 
             goods=c("wood","wood", "wood","wood", "wood", "steel", "steel", "steel", "steel"))
df
```

We have exchanges between multiple countries that have different IDs.
I want to sum all the exchanges between country A and country B. Between country A and country C. etc. the goods exchanged.
That is, in the end, I'd like to have

ID_1  // ID_2  //  Sum_exchangeAB
ID_1  // ID_3  //  Sum_exchangeBC
....
ID_n  // ID_n  // Sumexchangenn

How can I do that in Dplyr? I tried group_by (ID_1, ID_2) then aggregate. Or summarise.

I tried for example the following:  dataset2 %>% group_by(ID_1, ID_2, exchange) %>% summarise(dataset2, sum_of_exchange=sum(exchange)) .
But this gives me the sum of all the exchange (that is, it returns one value). Not the sum of exchange between two countries.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated!!

Comment: *I tried group_by (ID_1, ID_2) then aggregate.* ... and what happened? Please post your code attempt and relay the issues you encounter such as errors or undesired results.

Comment: What is your expected  output given the example you shared?

Comment: Am I right to assume that you want to sum the exchange of a to b and b to a? And so on?

Comment: Yes Deschen. I have a country-pair dataset. I have for many good the exchange between countries. I want to sum all the exchange between countries for all goods.

Comment: I tried for example the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_id = paste0(str_sort(c(ID_1, ID_2)), collapse = '-')) %>%
  group_by(new_id) %>%
  summarize(exchange = sum(exchange))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  new_id exchange
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 a-a           1
2 a-b          21
3 a-c          34
4 a-d           3
5 a-e           5
6 b-b           6
7 b-c          82
8 b-d           9
```

UPDATE: it seems the TO wants to append the sum to the original data which can be done with:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_id = paste0(str_sort(c(ID_1, ID_2)), collapse = '-')) %>%
  group_by(new_id) %>%
  mutate(sum_exchange = sum(exchange)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
  ID_1  ID_2  other exchange goods new_id sum_exchange
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 a     a     1            1 wood  a-a               1
2 a     b     bu          13 wood  a-b              21
3 a     c     34          34 wood  a-c              34
4 a     d     3            3 wood  a-d               3
5 a     e     5            5 wood  a-e               5
6 b     b     6            6 steel b-b               6
7 b     a     jud          8 steel a-b              21
8 b     c     82          82 steel b-c              82
9 b     d     9            9 steel b-d               9
```

Comment: Almost I think but I can't reproduce it. When I replace the "IDs" by the real IDs in the dataset, the new_id becomes very unclear. I don't know what it is. It is not the merge of the ID's for sure and doesn't correspond to anything in the dataset. However, there is a real mapping which means I'm almost there.

Comment: The problem comes from the last command (summarize...). Before that, the new_id is the good one: the joint of ID1 and ID2. But after summarize, the new_id becomes completely different.

Comment: If it doesn‘t work with your real data, then please share a small example of your real data. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please also see my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you !!!

Comment: If it works, please upvote the answer and/or choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID_1, ID_2) %>% summarise(Sum_Exchange = sum(exchange))
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ID_1 [2]
  ID_1  ID_2  Sum_Exchange
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
1 a     a               1
2 a     b              13
3 a     c              34
4 a     d               3
5 a     e               5
6 b     a               8
7 b     b               6
8 b     c              82
9 b     d               9
```

You can then remove identical IDs to omit AA, BB.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID_1, ID_2) %>% 
  summarise(Sum_Exchange = sum(exchange)) %>% 
  filter(ID_1 != ID_2)
```

**add-on from comment**

Combine dataframes with `{dplyr}`'s `bind_rows(df1, df2)`.
Mind you that `bind_rows()` will generate new columns for variables/columns that do not exist in the original data frame and fill cells of existing columns with no value with `NA`.
You can force, certain values into the same column/variable by renaming such a variable.

For your problem at hand. Check what you want/need. The original data frame comes with `other, goods` variables. Thus, these are not existing in the summarised data frame. Doing a `bind_rows()` will populate these with NA. To get the `Sum_Exchange` into the `exchange` variable, rename that column.

Comment: I think that‘s not what the TO wants. Instead they want to sum the results for e.g. a/b and b/a.

Comment: Perfect. Still one question. How do I get this but in addition to the dataset. That is, I mutate this last variable in order to have my original dataset+SUMXchange

Comment: as amended in the answer, check what you want. You either need to rename the cols first and then bind or bind and have the exchange values different from Sum_Exchange. Good luck!